# Как на wamp подгрузить проект из другой директории, не входящей в корневую?

Tags: localhost, virtual-hosts, wamp

Не хватает места на диске C. Решила разместить папки проектов на другом диске. Виртуальный сервер создан, пути до проектов прописаны, но при запуске выдаются ошибки, видимо не видит один или несколько файлов.
Может у кого-то такие попытки увенчались успехом? Поделитесь как?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoveflow! Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос текст ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в отключенном short_open_tag в php.ini Поэтому сыпались ошибки синтаксиса, а ошибки наличия файлов были ввиду лишнего символа в пути в httpd-vhosts.conf у Apache

Но все заработало, слава инструкциям! Всем peace